# Electron app to utilize GraphQL and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, graphql, electron

Electron application was built 2 years back that allows you to create an activity with an individual at a set time (think of creating an appointment/meeting).
The application was built using the following:

- Polymer frontend
- several simple php scripts (1 script file per action) eg: get.php, add.php, etc...
- Node.js (electron app)
- MySQL

The application was running ok, not really real-time when new activities are added there would need to be a navigation to a different "page" or a refresh to bring in the new data.

I've decided to rework the application using new technology and hopefully make it more of a "real-time" application.

This is where graphql (Never experienced) and mongodb (previously used) would come in.
And as for the php scripts, I will be replacing the backend with just expressjs moving forward.

Frontend is built using Polymer and there is a component called  which is a representation of ajax calls. This is my current restful call.

```
<iron-ajax 
   id="getPost"
   auto
   url="http://blitz.com/Activity/getActivity.php"  <!--getName.php--> etc...
   handle-as="json"
   on-response="handleResponse"
   last-response="{{activityResponse}}">
</iron-ajax>
```

This is where I believe if I can "implement" this into a GraphQL call, I would be able to learn more about how GraphQL works and how it is implemented. Also regards to GraphQL where would this be hosted if I were to bring the application online if I do need to host it? From my understanding GraphQL is quite similar to rest.

Database currently is broken down into several tables and will continue to increase the amount of tables if I have more ideas for the application, but for now it is only USERS table, ACTIVITIES table, POSTS table.
Additional features down the line would be like a logon functionality which I will need to figure out if adding a new table would be the right call or if I would use like a google sign-in.

If I were to use mongodb as it is a non-relational database. What would be the best practice for this application?

Would I just have 1 database and 1 collection to handle all the information? 
assuming collection is based on the following information

```
{
 id: 1,
 host_name:"bob",
 guest_name:"bill",
 activity:"basketball",
 time:"12:12:12 01/01/01",
 answer:"accepted"
}
```

As this is an electron application, I can just bundle everything up into an application and just host the backend and the database itself, express + mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need try [GraphQL Subcriptions](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/).

For Mongodb, keep it like relational on schema-free in order to make it easy to access. [Source](https://codenoid.github.io/posts/panduan-lengkap-mendesain-row-document-di-schemaless-database/)